# Problems connecting BLE with ESP32. Return gatt status 62

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, arduino-esp32

We have been using hundreds of ESP32 Devkit V1 boards in a device using a BLE connection for several years now.

Since one month ago, the latest units of ESP32 Devkit V1 that I have buy, they give BLE connection error with any android app, even loading their own examples in Arduino as "BLE notify.ino".

Could it be a hardware error? or is it due to the ESP32 upgrade to BLE 5.0? Can someone provide some information?

This is the link to the example I'm testing with:
https://github.com/nkolban/ESP32_BLE_Arduino/blob/master/examples/BLE_notify/BLE_notify.ino

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Have you asked the manufacturer of the ESP32 Devkit V1?

Comment: Hi! Yes, I wrote to Espressif with my problem because I think that its an error of hardware but i didn't receive response